# SQL: Selecting items per day but strip multiple entrys

Tags: php, sql

I got an accesslog which records every click on every project a (registered) user makes. By joining tables i get a nice view per user which looks like this:

ID | ProjectTitel | Releasedate of Project | Time it was clicked

with this code:

```
$request = "
    SELECT
        u.id,
        u.nachname,
        u.vorname,
        u.login,
        al.project,
        DATE_FORMAT(al.date, '%d. %b %Y, %H:%i') as date,
        a.titel,
        DATE_FORMAT(a.datum, '%d. %b %Y') as datum
    FROM
        user as u
        JOIN accesslog al ON al.user = u.id
        LEFT JOIN ausschreibungen as a ON al.project = a.id
    WHERE
        al.date >= '$interval_from'
        AND al.date <= '$interval_to'
        AND al.project != 0
        AND u.id = ".(int)$_GET['userid']."
    ORDER BY al.date DESC
        ";
```

Naturally the Output gives me every click on every project every time.

So, now for the real Problem, the shown Data should be reduced to only show one click per Project per Day.

i tried Grouping it by Day, which of course did not work, and by project, which of course did't work either.

```
User Table:
ID | Name | other useless stuff
accesslog Table:
User ID | ProjectID | Time
ausschreibungen Table:
Project ID | Project name | other useless stuff
```

I would need something like show me all entrys for this day, but strip multiple ones.

Is this complexity still possible while changing the sql-statement or do i need to evaluate the data with php?

If the latter is the only possibility, any suggestions to where to start?

Have a nice day!

Solution:

```
$request = "
        SELECT DISTINCT
            u.id,
            u.nachname,
            u.vorname,
            u.login,
            al.project,
            DATE_FORMAT(al.date, '%d. %b %Y') as date,
            a.titel,
            DATE_FORMAT(a.datum, '%d. %b %Y') as datum
        FROM
            user as u
            JOIN accesslog al ON al.user = u.id
            LEFT JOIN ausschreibungen as a ON al.project = a.id
        WHERE
            al.date >= '$interval_from'
            AND al.date <= '$interval_to'
            AND al.project != 0
            AND u.id = ".(int)$_GET['userid']."
        GROUP BY al.project, date

        ORDER BY al.date DESC
            ";
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: DISTINCT will only remove true duplicates; if your date field has (for example) hours in it then multiple clicks may still show. Otherwise, that's a good approach.

Comment: yes, tried that, but not working.
1 entry seems to vanish, cant get my hand on which but the same project still shows up multiple times per day

and to my previous commentor, yes datefield includes everything done to seconds.

Comment: distinct is probably the last thing you should use... the problem is the level of precision of the date/time data ... I (usually) hate distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this (untested) query. You need to treat the various logged date/time values as just the date (I think)

```
$request = "
    SELECT
        u.id,
        u.nachname,
        u.vorname,
        u.login,
        al.project,
        date(al.date)
        a.titel,
        MIN(a.datum)
    FROM
        user as u
        JOIN accesslog al ON al.user = u.id
        LEFT JOIN ausschreibungen as a ON al.project = a.id
    WHERE
        al.date >= '$interval_from'
        AND al.date <= '$interval_to'
        AND al.project != 0
        AND u.id = ".(int)$_GET['userid']."
    GROUP BY
        u.id,
        u.nachname,
        u.vorname,
        u.login,
        al.project,
        date(al.date)
        a.titel
    ORDER BY date(al.date) DESC
        ";
```

Comment: As in this form, it does not work.
While trying to adept the general idea, when changing adding the MIN() element it will only show the latest entry.

I just tried to GROUP BY al.project, date while i changed it to DATE_FORMAT(al.date, '%d. %b %Y') as date so it only shows the days and ignores hours i now got it to work

Comment: will include the new query inside the first post.